# Reducing Array length for highcharts, while keeping optimal amount of information

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, optimization, highcharts

we are showing our users a highcharts graph that is fed by an array of single data points (looks like a regular stock market graph). That was fine until now, since we only served around 100k points into that chart, but now we are getting to limits of 500k+ and the front-end (react) starts really suffering with that amount of data passed in.

On top of that, the details won't even be visible anymore to the user and we thought about preparing the array in the backend already to only contain 10% or so of the data points to show the same trend, but with unnoticeably less data points.

I looked at simplify-js, but that is more for 2d graphs and returns different lengths for the arrays, depending on the optimization (each graph shows 3 lines from 3 arrays, and simply-js returns 49, 500 and 900 of data length, even though all arrays had the initial same length).

Any idea what optimizer to use or would you advise to only loop over the arrays and take every 10th element for example?

Thanks!

Highcharts Boost does a great job here! However, now the lines get really uneven (only using boost on react-highcharts) meaning there is sudden jumps in the line (see image): [image]
When zooming in, the lines eventually smoothen!

Comment: There are couple ways to increase the performance and readability of a chart with a huge amount of data. Firstly, you can try `data grouping` (http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping). Secondly, you can use `boost` module (https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/175-highcharts-performance-boost/). Example: https://jsfiddle.net/j5Lwm17b/.

Comment: Thanks Paul, that's exactly doing the job! Didn't know boost before, but it seems super powerful in showing huge datasets!

Comment: Please check the updated question, as the rendering is pretty ugly now :/